# F# If-Then-Else trouble

Tags: f#

```
let downTo n = 

    if (n.Equals(0)) then
        printfn "\n Empty List Provided \n";;
    else
        List.rev(List.init n (fun index -> index + 1));;
```

I'm trying to create a list 'n' length, if a number greater than 0 is passed. If not, print an error message. The List works by itself, but not in the If-Else statement. How can this be accomplished? Please help.

Comment: Is the `;;` after `printfn` intentional.  This is probably your problem

Comment: @JohnPalmer : I would think it's that one branch returns unit and the other returns a list...

Comment: Do you want to print an error? Might be better with more context, but returning `[]` or `None` might be closer to the "functional" way. If an empty list is ok then you do not need a function for this and can just do `[n .. -1 .. 1]` to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 6):

F# `if` expressions are expressions not statements.  What this means is that the two parts of the expression need to have the same type.  In this case, one side has a type of `int list` and the other side has a type of `unit`.

Something like this would work for you better:

```
let downTo n =
    if (n.Equals(0)) then
        printfn "\n Empty List Provided \n"
        []
    else
        List.rev(List.init n (fun index -> index + 1))
```

or, alternatively, you could throw an exception but this has the drawback that you have to do a `try/catch` around it.

Comment: List.rev(List.init n (fun index -> index + 1)) already accomplishes your if-else by itself. Is there anyway to print an error or message if zero is passed? I'm trying to do one if-else statement, not two functions. Thanks.

Comment: @Antonio You can't unless you throw an exception. Just printing something has type `unit`, whereas the core functionality returns `'a list`, which means that types of both of your conditional branches do not unify. It's in the first paragraph of the answer :)

Comment: You can print right in `if` branch (sorry, hard to format whitespaces in comment):  `let downTo n =
    if (n.Equals(0)) then 
        printfn "\n Empty List Provided \n"  
        []  
    else  
        List.rev(List.init n (fun index -> index + 1))`

Comment: @Petr that's probably better than what I had originally